# Vue pass data from child component to child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

So I have a structure like this

```
<Root>
<HomeNav> router-view
<RouterLink>
<RouterLink>
<RouterLink>
<RouterLink>
<RouterLink>
<Home> router-view
<RouterLink>
```

Now, each of HomeNav router links is changing the data in  component by passing data to root, however that means that I need to bind that data:

```
      <router-view v-bind:title="title" v-bind:text="text" v-bind:youtube="youtube" v-bind:transition="transition"></router-view>
```

and run the functions on created and updated:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: Variables,
  created: function () {
    path = pathname.pathname();
    pathLenght = pathname.countPathLenght(path);
    this.homeText(this.data);
  },
  updated: function () {
    path = pathname.pathname();
    pathLenght = pathname.countPathLenght(path);
    Pace.restart()
    this.homeText(this.data);
  },
  methods: {
    homeText(data) {
      data = toogleData.checkText(data);
      this.title = data[0];
      this.text = data[1];
      this.youtube = data[2];
    }
  }
})
```

However, the problem is I don't need that data on all of the routes and I don't need to trigger this.homeText function or bind that specific data on every single root. It is only needed on homepage, so the first route.

So the question is, is it possible to directly pass data from HomeNav component to Home component without having all that code in global (root) component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place for the MessagePump that the VueJs documentation proposes. It is in essence and unbound Vue object that acts as an intermediary between objects. This allows you to define and call events on the pump which gets passed to the appropriate component.

```
window.MessagePump = new Vue({});

Vue.Component(
    'HomeNav',
    {
        ...
        data: function () {
            return {
                homeText: 'something'
            }
        },
        ...
        mounted: function () {
            var thisArg = this
            MessagePump.$on(
                'homeTextChanged',
                function(newText) {
                    thisArg.homeText = newText;
                }
            );
        }
        ...
    }
);

Vue.Component(
    'Home',
    {
        ...
        mounted: function () {
            MessagePump.$emit('homeTextChanged', 'To This');
        }
        ...
    }
);
```

This will trigger the event and the changing of homeText from 'something' to 'To This'.

Comment: looks great @Justin MacArthur, how to do it if 2 variables need changing i.e. title and text?

Comment: From what I remember every parameter after the name of the event is mapped to the function. so `$on(name, arg1, arg2, ..., argN)` is called with `$emit(name, 'arg1', 'arg2',..., argN)`

Comment: Can MessagePump also have a different name if I want to use it for something else too? I.e MessagePump2?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want. Just change `window.MessagePump` to `window.<YourName>` to make it respond to the name you select. You can even have multiple though the value of that is diminished as you can add organization to the event names instead.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that